# When a restriction of a function is bijective, then is the original function bijective?

Tags: functions

**Given a function $f : A \to B$ and $C \subseteq A$, when $f|_C$ is bijective, then is $f$ bijective?**

My initial assumption would be yes, since the domain of the restriction is a subset of the original one, meaning it should be a portion of the original's domain, and if the restriction of the function is bijective, then surely the original one is bijective. However, I am not certain about this, and I would appreciate if somebody helps in clearing this up. Our professor never discussed this so I am not sure if I missed some points or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if the restriction of the function is bijective, then surely the original one is bijective.

While the other answer already gave an example showing you are wrong, let me explain more intuitively why your logic is faulty.

I have 5 pairs of shoes. Let's take a look at the following statement:

> "All my shoes are brown".

Now, I also noticed that if I restrict the collection of my shoes to just my everyday shoes, my dancing shoes and my hiking shoes, then the statement above is *true*.

Can I, from what I wrote above, conclude that the statement is true in general?

Of course not. My hiking shoes are blue.

Comment: I see. Your corrections are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily, you can lose injectivity.

For example, $x^2$ is bijective on $[0,1]$ but not on $[-1,1].$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. :)